# Why are DOM lithiations sometimes conducted at −78 °C and othertimes conducted at elevated temperatures?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

I'm looking specifically at *n*-butyllithium. I've noticed a number of lithiation reactions are conducted at −78 °C, whereas I've encountered papers conducting these reactions at elevated temperatures, up to 60 °C or 70 °C in some cases, under an inert atmosphere of course.

Is there a particular reason for lowering the temperature in some cases and not in others? Does it relate to minimizing side reactions of other groups in the molecule, or does it primarily have to do with stability of the ending lithium reagent at various temperatures? If the latter, does having multiple directing groups assist in stability?

Comment: Solvent is also a factor. nBuLi reacts with THF at rt

Comment: there is no uniform answer, it is a case-by-case situation.  But generally you want to perform any reaction at the lowest temperature it proceeds at, because the lower temperature, the less side reactions occur. Buthyllitium is a very active compound, so many reactions could proceed at liquid nitrogen temperature (!) but liquid nitrogen is costlier than dry ice, so people usually settle at -78 as a practical temperature. However, when substrate needs a little push, or if you want thermodynamic control, elevated temperature might be used.

Answer (score 5):

The reason a given set of conditions used in any given reaction is likely fairly arbitrary unless you're following a paper where the conditions have been extensively optimised (for instance in an OPR&D paper where a process group has rigorously screened) - as has been discussed here before, −78 °C  is a convenient temperature to run reactions, so if it works at −78 °C, its unlikely anyone will ever bother to warm it up.

That said, in Clayden's [*Organolithiums: Selectivity for Synthesis*](https://www.elsevier.com/books/organolithiums-selectivity-for-synthesis/clayden/978-0-08-043261-8) (which is probably the most comprehensive reference of R–Li chemistry I can think of), a table of directing groups and representative conditions *is* presented. I've included the table below, but the actual text has a discussion of the various groups and a discussion of the representative conditions used. As a general guide, it seems that temperature is largely dictated by:

- the activating/deactivating nature of the directing group
- the sterics of the directing group
- the stability of the directing group, with low temperatures required in the case of electrophilic groups like the carbamate to prevent nucleophilic addition that would occur at higher temperature

As a general point, as temperatures get higher, the stabilisation of the anion by the directing group becomes less important to the overall energy and as such at higher temperatures, one would (generally) expect selectivity to drop.

[image]

<sub>Summary of directing groups used in DoM reactions with typical reaction temperatures. Taken from Clayden, J. *Organolithiums: Selectivity for Synthesis;* Pergamon: Oxford, U.K., 2002; p 34.</sub>